# Get latitude,longitude without touch

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

How to find user current location latitude,longitude without touch event?I searched in internet but i get latitude,longitude only touch event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use MyLocationOverlay for get current location.

```
   MyLocationOverlay whereAmI  = new MyLocationOverlay(this,mapview); 

   GeoPoint myLocationGeoPoint = whereAmI.getMyLocation();

   float latitude = myLocationGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;

   float longitude = myLocationGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
```

Comment: Ganesh: I already added this point positionOverlay.setLocation(location);

Comment: if u get lat,long value from location, use this.  int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);

Comment: I added this point:
positionOverlay.setLocation(location);

Double geoLat=location.getLatitude()*1E6;
      Double geoLng=location.getLongitude()*1E6;
      GeoPoint point=new GeoPoint(geoLat.intValue(),geoLng.intValue());

Answer (score 3):

I've answered to similar question of yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11946224/940096). Take a look at that. **It doesn't need the google maps.**

```
public class LocationSampleActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener 
{
    TextView tv;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);         
        tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);    
    }

    private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener 
    {
        @Override 
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {    
            if (location != null) {
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
            String str = "\n CurrentLocation: "+
                "\n Latitude: "+ location.getLatitude() + 
                "\n Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();       
              tv.append(str);  
              speak(location);
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(LocationSampleActivity.this,"Error onProviderDisabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }    
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(LocationSampleActivity.this,"onProviderEnabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Toast.makeText(LocationSampleActivity.this,"onStatusChanged",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

It will update your current location's latitude & longtitude into the `TextView` without touch simply. Please add the important permission into your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />       
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Spk:It is working in emulator only.but i installed my real device it will not automatically get user current location.